# math concepts in creating a calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a program for my college class that is to create a calculator. Each time I am trying to calculate numbers with decimals I divide the last digit entered by `n` and add the result to `existing number`. I then update the variable `n` by multiplying it by 10

```
(i.e. 1.23=1+2/10+3/100)
```

However, when I am trying to type a number such as 0.002 my code does not work because computer cannot comprehend what does 0.0 means. Please, let me know your thoughts, as I need your help desperately!

```
if (checkDecimal==1&&checkOperation==0){
  main=main+digit/n;
  setText ("result", main);
  n=10*n;
onEvent("button.", "click", function(event) {
  if (main2==null){
  setText ("result", main + ".");
  checkDecimal=1;
```

Comment: what do you mean the computer can not comprehend it? What is the error? Javascript supports floats. I works fine when I write ```let x = 0.0``` in my repl

Comment: Slightly off-topic: I'd suggest to build up the number as a string (while being entered by the user), then parse it as late as possible (i.e. right before doing a calculation). It's simpler, less prone to rounding errors, and keeps open the possibility to implement a correction key (backspace).